# mysql: store a DEFAULT value as a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am wondering how to store the value of a primary key, auto-incremented by "DEFAULT" so that I can insert it as a value in another table row.

So far I have:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sales (
            sale_id,
            sale_amt,
            sale_date) 
        VALUES (
            DEFAULT,  # <--- how to store the resulting value of this?
            '$amt',
            '$date'
            )";
```

I need the specific value created by "DEFAULT" to be stored, so that I can insert it into another table's row. How do I do this with either PHP or MySQL?

Comment: i think u need foregin key rather than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL:
You can find this in MySQL by using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, as the last insert ID will be returned that you inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT value.

`$sql = "INSERT INTO sales (
            sale_id,
            sale_amt,
            sale_date) 
        VALUES (
            DEFAULT,  # <--- how to store the resulting value of this?
            '$amt',
            '$date'
            )";`

`sql2 = "INSERT INTO records (
            sale_id,
            customer_name,
            other_info)
         VALUES (
            LAST_INSERT_ID(),      <-------- correct sales_id
            '$name',
            '$info');`

Comment: Consider the warning on the docs for [mysql_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php): "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.".

Comment: You're right.  Removing the PHP and sticking solely to mySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  You use `last_insert_id()` to retrieve it AFTER you've performed the first insert.

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (baz)
SELECT @id := last_insert_id();
INSERT INTO other (id, parent) VALUES (null, @id)
INSERT INTO yetanother (id, parent) VALUES (null, @id)
```

Note that `last_insert_id()` is not smart and will return the id of the **LAST** insert you did. If you do two inserts, and then try to get the ids, you'll get the id of the second (last) insert.